# Al parsear un array de fecha(en string) solo parsea el primer item y los demas me devuelve InvalidDate

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente problema:
Dada este array de fechas en formato string:

`let arrayStringDate = ["10/01/1995", "20/01/1995", "21/01/2010", "25/01/2010"]`

Estoy intentando parsearlo todo en `Date` de la siguiente manera:

`let parsedArray =  arrayStringDate.map(date => new Date(date));`

El resultado es que parsea solo el primer item y los demas me indica que son invalidos:

```
[Sun Oct 01 1995 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central), Invalid Date, Invalid Date, Invalid Date]<br>
```

Tambien lo intente hacer recorriendo el array item por item pero obtengo el mismo resultado. Como se puede observar, **solo parsea el primer string**, los demas causan error. ¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato de fecha por defecto en Javascript es `mm/dd/yyyy`, pero, también puede trabajar con formato `yyyy/mm/dd` y solo necesitas:

- Crear un arreglo, separando las partes con `.split('/')´
- Invertir el orden con `reverse()`
- Unir nuevamente con `.join('/')`

```js
let arrayStringDate = ["10/01/1995", "20/01/1995", "21/01/2010", "25/01/2010"];
let parsedArray =  arrayStringDate.map(date => {
    let parts = date.split("/").reverse();
    return new Date(parts.join('/'));
});
console.log(parsedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Las fechas deben de estar en formato mm/dd/yyyy asi:

```js
let arrayStringDate = ["10/01/1995", "11/01/1995", "12/01/2010", "5/01/2010"]



     let parsedArray =  arrayStringDate.map(x => new Date(x));
     
     console.log(parsedArray);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, una pregunta, no hay ninguna forma de elegir el formateo del Date a la hora de instanciarlo ?